# Salesforce email to case passing parameter values

Tags: email2case

Im using email to case to create a case. Im using mailto link to open the default mail application. My requirement is, is it possible to send any parameter value in mailto link so that i can change some default values when case is created.

Thanks,
IRaj.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_mailto

Comment: Hi Mihai, Thanks for your reply. I need to send some field values like picklist value when sending email. But from one of the post i found this is not possible. We can only send subject value in Email-to-Case.